# Error when updating google play services GCM

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm attempting to update the play services GCM, by changing the following line:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.2.1'
```

to:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:12.0.0'
```

I then get the message "Install repository and sync project". When I do this, I get the dialog "Finding Available SDK Components", and a little while after another message popup:

```
"Could not find dependency "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:12.0.0"
```

My full build.gradle file, if it helps, is:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:12.0.0'
    compile 'net.danlew:android.joda:2.9.3.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.3.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.okio:okio:1.8.0'
}
```

Comment: GCM was replaced by FCM (Firebase Cloud Messaging) you should migrate to that. You also need to include the google repository in your gradle. Please see how to setup google play services https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup

Comment: Thanks. The only features of GCM that I was using were GcmNetworkManager and PeriodicTask. In this case, should I still upgrade to Firebase?

Comment: Yes you can use FirebaseJobDispatcher https://github.com/firebase/firebase-jobdispatcher-android